# Insertion Speed in LinkedList

Tags: c#, performance, templates, generics, linked-list

While performance testing, I noticed something interesting.

I noticed that the very first insertion into a LinkedList(C# Generics) is extremely slower than any other insertion done at the head of the list. I simply used the C# template LinkedList and used AddFirst() for each insertion into the LinkedList. Why is the very first insertion the slowest?

---

***First Five Insertion Results:***

First insertion into list: 0.0152 milliseconds

Second insertion into list(at head): 0.0006 milliseconds

Third insertion into list(at head): 0.0003 milliseconds

Fourth insertion into list(at head): 0.0006 milliseconds

Fifth insertion into list(at head): 0.0006 milliseconds

***Performance Testing Code:***

```
        using (StreamReader readText = new StreamReader("MillionNumbers.txt"))
        {
            String line;
            Int32 counter = 0; 
            while ((line = readText.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                watchTime.Start();
                theList.AddFirst(line);
                watchTime.Stop();
                Double time = watchTime.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
                totalTime = totalTime + time; 
                Console.WriteLine(time);
                watchTime.Reset();
                ++counter; 
            }
            Console.WriteLine(totalTime);
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
            Console.WriteLine(totalTime / counter); 
        }
```

Comment: I suspect that some resources for the linked list are only allocated once something is first inserted into the list.

Comment: Please show your benchmarking code. I would be entirely unsurprised if this were just something to do with the way you're measuring.

Comment: May be the linkedlist creation internally has been delayed till you invoke AddFirst() for first time.

Comment: Personally, I suspect this is JIT time. We would need to see the code to comment, though.

Comment: @Jon Almost the same code as prior. I don't think that it has anything to do with how i'm measuring...?

Comment: @Marc - sorry updated with the code!

Comment: @BlueButtons: I suspect it has *everything* to do with how you're measuring. You're measuring *a single call*. That's like trying to measure a nation's health by looking at a single person. You've also not shown whether you've ever called `AddFirst` on *any* list before this code. See my answer for another benchmark.

Comment: @Jon no, i've not called AddFIrst prior to this code. Hmm, I don't think i'm quite understanding. I'm measuring each insertion as it occurs 1 million times over. Could you re-explain why measuring the insertion (the way i've done it) is dangerous? Also, i'm not all that familiar with what is meant by timing the JITing of AddFirst. Do you mean that I could be measuring the dynamic translation when timing this way? How does this work? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: @BlueButtons: You haven't shown doing things a million times though - you've shown it once. Is this actually happening in a loop? The JIT compilation is what happens the first time you call a method - it converts IL to native code.

Comment: @Jon The textfile i'm reading from contains one million numbers (counting 1 through to 1 million) each on a separate line. Hence, I add every line in the textfile into my LinkedList - creating one million different insertions into the LinkedList. Each insertion is timed. By the end, i take the total amount of time all the insertions (combined) have taken, and divide that by one million in order to get an average insertion speed. However, I was more wondering why the first insertion (inserting the number 1) took longer than any other insertion that occurred (2 - 1 000000 )...

Comment: @BlueButtons: But your time taken to measure the "first line" is from a single call. Measuring just a single call is never a good idea, *especially* when it's the first call to that method as you add JITting time. So yes, you've got a million calls in total, but your 0.0152 figure is from a single call, right?

Comment: @Jon, right. So adding all of these single calls up and dividing by a million is a bad idea huh. I had thought this would be OK as i'd be getting an average of a million 'single insertions.'I guess i'm just confused as to why measuring a single call would be bad - could you explain a specific example by any chance? (Aside from the first call - i understand why that may not be good now)

Comment: @BlueButtons: But you're not averaging a million *first* insertions, are you? You're just measuring the first call. That's problematic, in the same way as guessing my "average time getting home from work" judging by a single day is problematic - it's affected by the weather, the buses, the trains, what I'm carrying etc. Also, it's generally a better idea to start the stopwatch, do a lot of work, then stop it. Otherwise you still have precision issues - if you measured how long it took you to walk a mile by measuring each metre separately, that would be worse than measuring the whole mile.

Comment: @Jon the object of my program was not to measure first insertions. It was to simply measure the speed of inserting items at the beginning of the list. However, after printing the values, i noticed every time i ran the test, the very first insertion was always the slowest. I was wondering why this was occurring. But, my program is not meant to measure first insertions - rather the speed at which inserting at the beginning of the linkedList occurs. Thanks for the responses and explanations, i understand what you were saying now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timing a single operation is very dangerous - the slightest stutter can make a huge difference in results. Additionally, it's not clear that you've done *anything* with `LinkedList<T>` before this code, which means you'd be timing the JITting of `AddFirst` and possibly even whole other types involved.

Timing *just the first insert* is rather difficult as once you've done it, you can't easily repeat it. However, you can time "insert and remove" repeatedly, as this code does:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Make sure we've JITted the LinkedList code
        new LinkedList<string>().AddFirst("ignored");

        LinkedList<string> list = new LinkedList<string>();        
        TimeInsert(list);
        list.AddFirst("x");
        TimeInsert(list);
        list.AddFirst("x");
        TimeInsert(list);
        list.AddFirst("x");        
    }

    const int Iterations = 100000000;

    static void TimeInsert(LinkedList<string> list)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
        {
            list.AddFirst("item");
            list.RemoveFirst();
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Initial size: {0}; Ticks: {1}",
                           list.Count, sw.ElapsedTicks);
    }
}
```

My results:

```
Initial size: 0; Ticks: 5589583
Initial size: 1; Ticks: 8137963
Initial size: 2; Ticks: 8399579
```

This is what I'd expect, as depending on the internal representation there's very slightly more work to do in terms of hooking up the "previous head" when adding and removing to an already-populated list.

My guess is you're seeing JIT time, but really your code doesn't really time accurately enough to be useful, IMO.

Comment: Ohhh Woaha! That's pretty smart how you do a garbage collection just before you measure the time. Pretty cool!

Comment: Jon, just on the flip side after calling Gc.Collect and Waitforpendingfinalizers() or while the CLR is executing this methods and asking the GC to do some collections, dont you think other .NET running programs may add up some difference to the results? I wonder if it has any thing to do with AppDoamins as well? I mean GC cleans only in this AppDomain and not in others or some thing?

Comment: @zenwalker: The CLR is not shared between multiple processes, so other running .NET applications do not influence the measurement.

Comment: @FlorianGreinacher
The same w.r.t GC right, while your asking it to do some collection work and other apps are creating some more random memory (lets assume) in such case?

Comment: @zenwalker: Sorry, I don't get your question. The CLRs (as well as their GCs) of different processes don't have any knowledge of and therefore no influence on each other.

Comment: @FlorianGreinacher
Sorry, let me rephrase. Yes i got that point, but my question was that when your asking for GC to clean up the memory, in other words if GC started to clean memory based on request from one end of the heap but on the same time few other apps running in the system may create memory (in this case lets assume huge random memory creation by those apps) so in such a case, still we do get accurate results? Or do you think it might affect the benchmarking result?

Comment: @zenwalker: In my opinion it does not influence the benchmark, as CPU time is distributed evenly among processes (with same priority), no matter how much memory a process is trying to allocate.